# Git Alias for creating branch names faster

Tags: git, bash, shell, alias

At work, my flow for fixing something is creating a branch `git checkout -b {GITUSERNAME}/ticket-{TICKET-NUMBER}` so like `git checkout -b oscar/ticket-1234`. I was wondering if there was a way I could make it so I could do `git nt 1234` to create a "new ticket branch" of 1234 and then `git cot 1234` to "checkout ticket 1234".

Comment: Are you working in a specific shell, and tried making a native alias? Have you tried a bash/python/perl/`$yourLangOfChoice` script? Have you tried *something*?

Comment: Yeah, I can make a bash script that's invoked in git with `!`, but was looking at how to do this with gitalias. I read the docs and, honestly, I don't really understand it fully. Sorry :\

Comment: I've never used git aliases, but I personally would just try [some examples](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases) and figure it out from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it. Add `--global` after `config` to make it global:

```
git config alias.nt '!f() { git checkout -b $(git config user.name)/ticket-${1}; }; f'
git config alias.cot '!f() { git checkout $(git config user.name)/ticket-${1}; }; f'
```

Note that this will only work if your `user.name` is one word!

Comment: Luckily, my username is. Thank you! I'll try it out.